# Can't add NPM libraries with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, npm

I'm trying to use Netbeans IDE to libraries to a project with npm, but the dialog seems to display corrupted characters, almost like there's a character set mismatch.

Is this issue with my configuration or a Netbeans bug?

This happens with a brand new JS project as well as existing ones.

Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 10
npm 4.2.0

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this? I am experiencing the same, except I'm on Ubuntu. Started to happen after Node reinstall

Answer (score 3):

First notice please, that this solution will modify the `package.json` in your source-folder. So, after you add a package, close the window (ignore the error-msgs) and open the `package.json` in the source-folder to fix the json-syntax manualy.

Exemplary:

```
"dependencies": {"electron                  ||||":"2.0.5    ||||",}
```

to:

```
"dependencies": {"electron": "2.0.5"}
```

(Need a bit knowing about JSON-Syntax maybe)

After saving the `package.json` go to the project-property-tool. You will see the correct package in the overview. You will have to still update the package and press OK.

I hope my instructions helps.

Regards

//Sunny